# How to enter product key for trial version of Office 2013

Tags: microsoft-office, product-key

My new laptop came with a trial version of Microsoft office Professional Plus, this trial lasts for 30 days. So I found a website that sells the key I need, here is the link to the website: http://www.just4keys.com/office-2013-pro-plus-key-download-p-33.html?zenid=69437ab569c823b7ac05e13ca0ee

My question is, how do I enter the product key for the full version before the end of the trial?

Answer (score 4):

I have used the process described in [this post](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-office_install/change-product-key-office-2013-home-and-business/da7b8b49-7d35-46b2-a257-8f330dd1450b)

**For 32 bit Windows:**
cscript "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15\OSPP.VBS" /inpkey:yourkeygoeshere

**For 64 bit Windows (assuming you are using 32 bit Office):**
cscript "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\OSPP.VBS" /inpkey:yourkeygoeshere

Obviously, you need to replace yourkeygoeshere with your product key.

Comment: Next time I here that Gnu/Linux users have to use the command line, I will not tell them that the command line is superior to graphical interface, or that Gnu/Linux has a superior graphical interface. Instead I will point them here to see that in Microsoft's system they **need** the command line to be allowed to use the graphical interface. (but only after days searching online)

Comment: Thanks it worked. Why microsoft don't tell us what to do, I don't know. I would not recommend this product (Microsoft) to a friend.